# sending email in Laravel 5 with google apps account does not work

Tags: php, email, laravel, google-apps, swiftmailer

i am now building one quite big sized enterprise grade web application on our production server.

while i was developing on local development server, sending mail was not a big concern, but in the live step it became a big pain in my butt.

i've searched like more than 3days and tried to use mandrill, postfix and sendmail driver options in the Laravel, still i could not get it happen.

so anyone, who experienced developing sending emails on Laravel with google apps account???

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=my app key

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mandrillapp.com
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@themandarin.co.kr
MAIL_PASSWORD=my api key
```

above is my .env file of the web application

and log shown below is the log, when the mail send fails

> [2015-07-02 17:56:16] production.ERROR: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at^M
>   535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 gs7sm4872423pbc.6 - gsmtp^M
>   "' in /home/thecorp-admin/Services/TheMandarin/Trinity/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
>   Stack trace:

just incase i will provide some useful information.

above shown link does not work with google apps accounts

Comment: Hi, I have been using Laravel to send email using business gmail accounts and haven't had too much issues. Does the account you are trying to use have two step authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer using gmails smtp server

In your App\Config\mail.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'smtp',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'sender@email.co.uk', 'name' => 'Ted notification'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'yourname@email.com',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => 'myPassword',
```

If you are using two step verification you need to get an app password. To do this go to your google account, sign in settings and add a new app. You will need to select other.
Google will give you a password which you will need to use in this config file

Comment: that is what i exactly did.

Comment: I am having error below:

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError e190sm2996547pfa.41 - gsmtp
"

Comment: You'll be getting that error if you either have an incorrect password or you have 2 step authentication set up. If you do you'll need a App password which you can get from your gmail account settings